# Set AcroField Text Size to Auto

Tags: itext, acrofields

Using `itextsharp`, I'm attempting to set the font size of my form's text fields to `auto`.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
Object d = 0.0;

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);

byte [] pdf;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);

    AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

    foreach (var f in fields.Fields.Keys)
    {
        fields.SetFieldProperty(f, "textsize", d, null);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(String field, String name, Object value, Int32[] inst)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Using `0f` instead of `d` in the call `SetFieldProperty` let me change the font size to `auto`.